# Get a scores of all users from the room after game completes in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm working on a multiplayer game in which there will be four rooms and each room will have multiple clients in it who are playing the game. After completing the game i want to send the score of all users to the server, store it in the array, compare it and want to return the name of the winner. So, how can i get the score of all the users from the room, after completing the game.

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 2000;
var hit = 0;

$('#hit').click(function() 
{
  hit++;
});

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("common");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

setTimeout(function() 
{
    var seconds_left = 15;
    var interval = setInterval(function() 
    {
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = --seconds_left;
        if (seconds_left <= 0)
        {
            // document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "Time's up!";
            clearInterval(interval);
          console.log(hit);
          $('#hit').attr("disabled", true);
          $('#score').html(hit);
          modal.style.display = "block";

        }
    }, 1000);
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

Above is the client side code for the game, game will be completed after 15 seconds, so my idea is i can send the data in `if(seconds_left <= 0)`, but how can i get the score of all the clients from the room.

Comment: I'm guessing `hit` is the score?

Comment: yes, hit is the score

Comment: You might want to emit the score back to the server or you could create an endpoint in which you'd send the score to so you can save it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to somehow identify users. Let's save them to object called users with key userName and value score. Just like that: `var users = { user1: 12, user2: 9 };`.
Than we have to send this data to server. We can do it like examle from official socket.io [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/)

```
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('connection', function () {
    console.log('Socket connected');
  });

  // here is your code to handle users actions. 
  // When the game is finished, you do it like this
  socket.emit('game finished', users);
</script>
```

On the server side you can listen for `game finished` event with data you want to parse.

Also, you can make requests to server with `ajax` to process score data, you can read about jQuery [implementation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [native JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Thanks @Grynets. I got your point of parsing the data. But i'm little bit confused. i.e. There are four uses in room. Then, how can sever notice that scores of all the users are submitted? Because, after storing scores of all the users only, i can compare and send it to all the users. Sorry, if this is the silly question, because i'm a beginner.

Comment: @DharaVihol In my point of view, your process with users in game should look something like this: 1. User come to the game. You emit event to server that user has come and provide some id to it (or name) whatever to identify him/her. Than  all users fulfill game room, they played and when the game is finished you emit event to server. There you store data in array. Just like this `[{room1: [scores]}]`. Than you check if array length is 4, if it is, you can compare results and `emit` results to users. If not, you can just wait until array fills and emit event.